# What happened to nothingtoinstall.com?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackauth

This is weird:

```
{
      "name": "Web Applications",
      "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/webapps/img/logo.png",
      "api_endpoint": "http://api.webapps.stackexchange.com",
      "site_url": "http://webapps.stackexchange.com",
      "description": "Q&A for power users of web applications",
      "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/webapps/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
      "aliases": [
        "http://nothingtoinstall.com"
      ],
      "state": "normal",
      "styling":
      {
        "link_color": "#163B6D",
        "tag_foreground_color": "#666666",
        "tag_background_color": "#FFF"
      }
}
```

I thought that we were to access the API from the domain name "nothingtoinstall.com" and that "webapps.stackexchange.com" was an alias - not the other way around. Not only that, but the name of the site is **completely** wrong.

This has also messed up some of my applications.

Please either explain what's going on or change it back.

Comment: this has to be a bug.

Comment: @Sky: Look at the link pointed to in the answer below - it doesn't even sound like a bug at all!

Comment: it appears so. But ultimately the relevant data is site_url and aliases. a proper handling of this data should simply re-migrate nothingtoinstall back to webapps.

Answer (score 2):

[The domain name is up for debate right now](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-verus-nothingtoinstall-com). Who knows whats going to happen

Comment: Wow... this really is a far reaching problem... now the domain name is redirecting!

Answer (score 0):

NothingToInstall has been rolled back to WebApps.StackExchange.  This has been discussed elsewhere, and should continue to be discussed elsewhere (read: no debate on StackApps, take it to the appropriate meta).

From the API perspective:

- WebApps.StackExchange became NothingToInstal

  - webapps.stackexcahange was an alias
  - state changed to "normal"
  - styling, icons, logos, etc. were all updated
- NothingToInstall became Webapps.StackExchange

  - nothingininstall became an alias for WebApps.StackExchange

NothingToInstall is still considered a "graduate" (ie. normal) site, and will retain its state, and distinct styling.  The idea of linking a site getting a distinct domain name due to beta graduation is what's being reworked here, nothing else.

In keeping with the issues we had with the initial NothingToInstall transition, the old site's API endpoint will live for at least the recommended StackAuth caching period (24 hours).  Right now both api.nothingtoinstall and api.webapps.stackexchange report on the same site (naturally the nothingtoinstall endpoint is no longer advertised in `/site`).

Comment: I understand that you want the debate somewhere else and I agree with that - I just wanted to ask from the point of view of the API.

Comment: @George - no problem at all with answering the API-relevant bits, and you didn't ask anything inappropriate or inappropriately, just nipping the urge in the bud as it were.